# JSON changes not staying?

Tags: javascript, json, attributes

I needed to manipulate a JSON object so d3.js would know how to render it. It was structured

```
{
    name:"Films",
    children:[...]
}
```

Later I looped through the children to add X and Y attributes to them similarly to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<jsonobject.children.length; i++) {
    jsonobject.children[i].x=123;
    jsonobject.children[i].y=456;
    console.log(jsonobject.children[i]);
}
```

When I logged each element after the attribute assignment, it was clear that the X and Y were valid. After exiting the loop, all the X and Y attributes of the children were `NaN`. It appears that the X and Y were 'reset' at each iteration.

Not sure if this this is a weird javascript thing, or if I'm doing something wrong.
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/6kwn857o/

Comment: `i,jsonobject.children.length` should be `i < jsonobject.children.length`

Comment: Impossible to say without the rest of your code. It's best if you set up a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem. (You can put your mind at rest. It's not a weird JavaScript thing. You are doing something wrong.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6kwn857o/